# R: read file, split into multiple dataframes

Tags: r

I have a file that is laid out in the following way:

```
# Query ID 1
# note
# note
tab delimited data across 12 columns
# Query ID 2
# note
# note
tab delimited data across 12 columns
```

I'd like to import this data into R so that each query is its own dataframe. Ideally as a list of dataframes with the query ID as the name of each item in the list. I've been searching for awhile, but I haven't seen a good way to do this. Is this possible?
Thanks

Comment: Please provide the reproducible example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

We have used comma instead of tab to make it easier to see and have put the body of the file in a string but aside from making the obvious changes try this.  First we use `readLines` to read in the file and then determine where the headers are and create a grp vector which has the same number of elements as lines in the file and whose values are the header for that line.  Finally split the lines, and apply `Read` to each group.

but aside from that try this:

```
# test data

Lines <- "# Query ID 1
# note
# note
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
# Query ID 2
# note
# note
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12"

L <- readLines(textConnection(Lines)) # L <- readLines("myfile")
isHdr <- grepl("Query", L)
grp <- L[isHdr][cumsum(isHdr)]
# Read <- function(x) read.table(text = x, sep = "\t", fill = TRUE, comment = "#")
Read <- function(x) read.table(text = x, sep = ",", fill = TRUE, comment = "#")
Map(Read, split(L, grp))
```

giving:

```
$`# Query ID 1`
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12
1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12
2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12

$`# Query ID 2`
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12
1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12
2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12
```

No packages needed.